# What are some good books on Islamic Psychology?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

Yesterday I attended one day workshop on Islamic Psychology. This is an emerging field and has lot of scope. When Secular psycology seems to promote gay relationship and other non islamic things, I think Islamic Psychology has lot of scope for resolving Muslim youth problems, even can benefit Non muslim youths.

For those who have been studying this field, can you suggest good books to read in this regard ?

Comment: have a search at [al-islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/])

Comment: lol, it is like when some asks for a particular fish, you just point to ocean and say it is inside it.. Anyway thanks for suggestion.

Comment: your question is an ocean. not a fish. there are thousands of books on Islamic Psychology and which to choose depends on your needs and interests.